# Oracle Stored Procedure view sys_refcursor

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures

I have an oracle stored procedure that is called from a third party reporting tool.  The stored procedure is not returning any rows when it's executing.

I know for a fact the query returns results, it's just something is going wrong in the `where` clause with the parameters being passed from the website.

I'm trying to see the query that is being executed but the logs do not show the query, only that it's calling the stored procedure. I don't have access to the website code to do a response write and display the stored procedure or the parameters.  Can you please provide guidance on how I can view the sys_refcursor from the stored procedure below? I'm using TOAD and when I use the toad script runner I don't see any results

Code

```
    create or replace procedure dolphin.report_four
    ( p_1    char,
     P_2    date,
     p_recordset   out sys_refcursor)
    AS
    Begin
    Select
    column_1,
    column_2,
    column_3

     from dolphin.tank
    where
     column_1 = 'BAIT' and
    column_2 = 'p_2'

   end report_four;
```

Answer (score 1):

Create a table for logging this procedure calls, and add `INSERT` statement within the procedure to add a row with parameters passed. Remember to `COMMIT;` after that.

Set the procedure query to:

```
select /*+ monitor MY_KEY_765746573*/
 f1, f2, ...
from ...
```

Make the app to invoke the procedure.

Then run

```
select sql_id, sql_fulltext from v$sql where sql_fulltext like '%MY_KEY_'||'765746573%';
```

Then place SQL_ID found into the call:

```
select dbms_sqltune.report_sql_monitor('YOUR SQL_ID HERE') from dual;
```

I hope logging table records along with SQL monitor report give you a clue.

Comment: Anybody following this advice should bear in mind that `dbms_sqltune` is part of the Tuning and Diagnostics pack, which is a chargeable extra on the Enterprise Edition. You should only use this package if you have the correct licensing in place.

Answer (score 1):

> "The stored procedure is not returning any rows when it's executing."

The code as posted executes a select statement but does not pass anything to the REF CURSOR. If this was a real procedure it would through an error when you attempted to run it. Presumably you've made a bish of editing the source for publication on StackOverflow so it's hard to tell whether this situation is a reflection of your actual code, but it ought to do something like this:

```
create or replace procedure dolphin.report_four
    ( p_1    char,
     P_2    date,
     p_recordset   out sys_refcursor)
    AS
Begin
    open  p_recordset for
        Select
            column_1,
            column_2,
            column_3
         from dolphin.tank
         where
         column_1 = p_1 and
         column_2 = p_2;
end report_four;
```

Opening the REF CURSOR associates the parameter with the query result set.

Comment: thank-you for the reply. You are correct I did edit the code to make it more simpler, I guess it had a negative effect. The problem is in the where clause with column_2='p_2'. I was trying to find a way to  see what the where clause is to identify the problem.  I did do an insert statement with p_2 and the parameter value is fine.  Thank-you for providing the REF CURSOR is the query result set. I thought it was the query itself.